# How to display Login and dismiss Settings - Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, authentication, storyboard

I am trying to figure out how to display Login (modal viewcontroller) from logout button and automate dismiss Settings (modal viewcontroller) from underneath of Login. You may see the storyboard layout:

http://cl.ly/2B3h0T130S1K1026201N

I tried to add this code into logout method in SettingsViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)logoutAccount {

      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

      UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
      UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
      [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

      [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES]; 

}
```

The problem is that it forced my app to freeze when I clicked to logout. Does anybody know what is wrong with it? Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the user logs in again, where do you want the app to be?  Let's say you want the app to be at the view controller where the settings button is (it looks that way from the storyboard).

Then that vc (the root vc in the navigation controller) can do this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    if (/*login is needed*/) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
        [vc setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

        [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES]; 
    } else {
        // normal view did appear logic
    }
}
```

The logout button can now just do this:

```
- (IBAction)logoutButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I have one more question about adding PasscodeViewController into it. You may see this question that I posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307120/display-passcode-pincode-upon-launching-the-app-storyboard Your help is much appreciated! Thanks!